# Stripping of white space seems broken

Tags: freemarker

I am moving some XSLT templates to freemarker due to better Java compatibility but freemarker seems to have issues with handling whitespace.  XML ends up with white space all over the place like this:

```
</fo:block>

</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>  <fo:table-cell  



>   <fo:block >
    <fo:inline  font-weight="bold"
```

I have tried adding the `strip_whitespace=true` directive but it has no effect.  It is the default so it is probably already meant to be working.

In XSLT all white space between XML blocks is collapsed.  This is made easier by placing any free text needs inside an `<xsl:text> example text including padding     </xsl:text>` element.

It seems that freemarker lacks control over the text nodes and there is no way to collapse the whitespace.

**UPDATE**: here is an example of a portion of the freemarker template where it generates the `fo:table-cell`

```
<#macro tableHeaderM tableHeader>
    <#list tableHeader.columns as column><@columnM column=column /></#list>
</#macro>
<#macro columnM column>
    <fo:table-column column-width="${column.width}cm" />
</#macro>
<#macro rowM row table>
    <fo:table-row><#list row.cells as cell><@cellM cell=cell table=table /></#list></fo:table-row>
</#macro>
<#macro cellM cell table>
    <fo:table-cell<@cellFormattingM cell=cell table=table />><@blockObjectsM blockObjects=cell.blockObjects /></fo:table-cell>
</#macro>
<#macro cellFormattingM cell table>
    <#if cell.border == true> border="0.1mm solid"</#if>
    <#if cell.pad == true> padding="3pt"</#if>
    <#if cell.shade == true> background-color="#eeeeee"</#if>
    <#if table.collapse == true> margin-top="5px"</#if>
</#macro>
```

Comment: Is the code posted the generated code from Freemarker?

Comment: @Huangism yes, but only a snippet as an example.  i could post a gist of the full file but i don't think it is necessary to explain the problem?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the Freemarker code you used to generate this? or just a piece of code to generate any block

Comment: @Huangism i added an update showing how i am adding the table elements.  during the cellFormattingM macro it is obviously adding 4 line breaks for each `#if` line.  i would have expected it to add none

Comment: Try this format `<#macro columnM column><fo:table-column column-width="${column.width}cm" /></#macro>` this is less readable but since your macros fairly short, it should be ok. That should kill a lot of the white space

Comment: @Huangism i don't think that is a good solution to the problem as it makes the template unreadable.  according to https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html there should be no breaks in the cellFormattingM macro with white-space stripping enabled

Comment: Yes I read the doc and that's why I suggest you try the approach in my previous comment. The white space is only ignored if your macro ONLY contains ftl tags or comments. Your macro has content for the if statements. It's not that readable but I had to do the same thing for some of my macros due to this limitation

Comment: @Huangism freemarker whitespace handling seems broken and the file will be impossible to understand with all the extra whitespace handling junk.  Coming from XSLT which handles white space perfectly this is a bit of a shock

Comment: Sorry you win some and you lose some

Comment: @MitchBroadhead To transform XML to XML use XSLT, by all means. That's what it's specialized on. For FreeMarker on the other hand, XML is just a possible data source, along with Java beans, etc. It outputs any kind of text, but doesn't know its meaning, so it can't format it, decide what whitespace is desired, etc. XSLT thinks in the XML information set (a tree), not in flat text.

Comment: @ddekany the java support was the reason i wanted to use freemarker.  i would have thought xml, html, xhtml and fo would be some of the primary targets for freemarker output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white-space stripping and trimming in FreeMarker is solely for removing white-space that's present in the template itself (i.e., white-space added for source code formatting). The white-space in your case is present in the data-model. Unfortunately, you need to pre-process the DOM to get rid of those (or insert with `?trim` and such). The FreeMarker DOM wrapper doesn't know which whitespace is insignificant.

**Update** (since the white-space doesn't come from the DOM):
`strip_whitespace` (white-space stripping) is by default `true`, so adding that won't remove more white-space. So your best bet is using `<#t>` (and maybe `<#rt>` and `<#lt>`) to remove more white-space explicitly.

Comment: that is not true.  it is not in the data model at all

Comment: using <#t>, <#rt> and <#lt> is a fail.  freemarker should handle white space correctly

Comment: AFAIK all generic(!) template languages has this problem... XSLT is much more knowledgeable about its input and output, but it's highly specialized. Anyway, I was thinking on how to solve this for a good while, and it's far from trivial to figure out the *intent* of the template author (which white-space is just formatting, and which meant to be there). It can't be done statically, part of it has to be done on runtime (dynamically). But I wanted to contribute it for a long time... never get to it, and API backward compatibility makes it even harder.

Comment: this is why i mentioned the XSLT `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` element.  if freemarker ignored all text outside of a tag like `<#text>This is some text (possibly including whitespaces)</#text>` then it would solve the problem?  there could be a mode that supported that feature which would allow backwards compatibility e.g. `<#ftl ignore_unwrapped_content="true">`

Comment: That in itself doesn't address proper indention. Without that, the output is still unintelligible, so you still had to pass a `Writer` to `Template.process` that parses and nice-formats XML. Also, if printing something is an explicit instruction, then it's not really a template anymore. The whole point of templates is that the program looks similar to the output. Otherwise you might as well use a real programming language, and write `print("foo")` instead of `<#text>foo</#text>` (which is very similar to `foo<#t>`, because hopefully most other WS is eliminated automatically by FreeMarker).

Comment: why would you want to nice format xml ?  it is for the machine to read.  there are a million ways to pretty print xml if you want to human read it.  i totally disagree that the whitespace should resemble the template format.  why would you want any line breaks in this scenario for example `<#macro>[BR]<#if>some writing</#if>[BR]</#macro>[BR]` results in 3 line breaks even if the condition is not met!!

Comment: I thought your want pretty output. If it's read by machine then people usually don't care about some extra whitespace. Or use a minifier instead of pretty printer. I didn't say that the output ws should resemble to the source. I said FM should only print the ws that the author meant to be printed... but that's at best difficult to figure out. But, in  the example you show FM only prints 1 `[BR]`, not 3 (even if you put the two `#if` tags into their own lines). And that whitespace can be eliminated if you add a *single* `<#t>` (which is terser than `<#text>some writing</#text>`).

Comment: i want the *template* to be pretty to work on and logical to understand not the *output*.  so i don't want random white space popping up in my output.  if you think about how php works for example, with `<?php` and `?>` you wouldn't expect any whitespace to be output while you are dealing with logical operators etc.  having to add `<#t>` to the end of practically every line is a fail.  looking at my template adding a text node `<#text>something</#text>` would result in a much more sane experience.  most of the text content is coming from fields anyway?

Comment: Whitespace is removed around tags like `#if`, `#list`, `#macro`, etc., if the tags are *in their own line*. If you want to put the text and the tag into the same line, only then you need to add that `<#t>`. Still better than adding the more verbose `<#text>...</#text>`, as far as I see. (BTW, be careful when you got two pieces of text next to each other, as by removing ws all over you might glue them together, which is now a semantic difference (corrupt output). That's one reason why FM doesn't remove ws too bravely.)

Comment: ok i will have to keep trying to understand the logic i guess.  i have used XSLT, XHTML (JSF), jsp, php, perl, bash etc. and I have never come across a templating language like freemarker that makes such a mess of handling text elements.  it seems like a problem that has already been solved in every other language through use of distinct text outputting areas

Comment: JSP, last time I used it, simply keeps *all* whitespace. Probably PHP too. That's the common thing to do. But, they have some kind of program blocks that aren't template languages inside, but usual languages. FM, as any MVC-oriented template language doesn't have such "program blocks". If you need such blocks a lot, it's probably not the right tool for the task. It's not a programming language like PHP or Java.

Comment: thanks for your help getting started with freemarker.  i seem to be getting over some of the problems.  it is quite a change from xml based templating.